# How to connect multi-bit output to more than one input?

Tags: logic, verilog, system-verilog

I want to make my module look more or less like in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKCBx.png). However I have trouble doing that because I either connect to one of the and gates or none of them, i don't know how to do this, tried multiple different things and I can't find anything on google. I know I'm really dumb and solution is probably so simple i overlooked it plenty of times but I really need help with this one. Below is the code.

```
module chain (A, B, SI, SE, CLK, Y, SO);

input A, B, SI, SE, CLK;
output Y, SO;
wire and1_wire,chain1,nand_wire, or1_wire, and2_wire,chain3, 
    cnt1_wire1, cnt1_wire2, cnt1_wire3, cnt1_wire4, cnt1_wire5, 
    cnt1_wire6, cnt1_wire7, cnt1_wire8;
wire [7:0] cnt1_wires;

assign cnt1_wires[7:0] = {cnt1_wire1, cnt1_wire2, cnt1_wire3, cnt1_wire4,
         cnt1_wire5, cnt1_wire6, cnt1_wire7, cnt1_wire8};

cnt cnt1(
    .SI(SI),
    .SO(cnt1_wires),
    .CLK(CLK)
    );

and02 and1(
    .A0(cnt1_wire1),
    .A1(cnt1_wire2),
    .Y(and1_wire)
    );

and02 and2(
    .A0(cnt_wire3),
    .A1(cnt_wire4),
    .Y(and2_wire)
    );

and02 and3(
    .A0(cnt_wire5),
    .A1(cnt_wire6),
    .Y(and3_wire)
    );

and02 and4(
    .A0(cnt_wire7),
    .A1(cnt_wire8),
    .Y(and4_wire)
    );

and02 and5(
    .A0(and1_wire),
    .A1(and2_wire),
    .Y(and5_wire)
    );

and02 and6(
    .A0(and3_wire),
    .A1(and4_wire),
    .Y(and6_wire)
    );

and02 and7(
    .A0(and5_wire),
    .A1(and6_wire),
    .Y(and7_wire)
    );

cnt cnt2(
    .SI(and7_wire),
    .SO(SO),
    .CLK(CLK)
    );
endmodule
```

Comment: you forgot to provide definition of other modules, `cnt` and `and02`. also you messed up naming of `cnt.._wire..`. sometimes you use `cnt_...` and sometimes `cnt1_...`.

Comment: Why do you have two instantiations of the ```cnt``` module? Your picture indicates you only want one counter. Also, what do you mean by "I either connect to one of the and gates or none"? Who is "I" in this sentence? The counter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem in your code is that you should switch the inputs and outputs of the assign statement you are using `assign cnt1_wires[7:0] = {cnt1_wire1, cnt1_wire2, cnt1_wire3, cnt1_wire4, cnt1_wire5, cnt1_wire6, cnt1_wire7, cnt1_wire8};`
since you want to connect the output of the counter module to the inputs of the and gates not vice versa, so the new assignment statement should look something like this

```
assign {cnt1_wire1, cnt1_wire2, cnt1_wire3, cnt1_wire4,
     cnt1_wire5, cnt1_wire6, cnt1_wire7, cnt1_wire8} = cnt1_wires[7:0];
```